# estoy intentando solucionarlo pero no le encuentro la solución

Tags: swift

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no logro resolverlo mi intención es al momento de registrar al usuario que aparezca el nombre del usuario en la pantalla de inicio con la cual se registro.

Comment: pon tu código y explica que error te sale, en el foro no es bien visto poner imágenes con la muestra que quieres resolver por que no es legible

Comment: eso es porque para obtener los datos del usuario registrado lo debes de obtener de la seguiente manera `let id = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid`

Comment: muchas gracias, pero ya solucione el problema gracias por los comentarios.

Comment: pues podrias poner la solución, asi si alguien le pasa lo mismo puede solucionar su problema.